# handle multiple processes running in the same environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i have two spring boot projects and they are connected with the same database and table but each one of them doing a different job, followed by fetching the data by using `JPA`then `restTemplet` to post the data into `JSON` API and update the records in the database accordingly and those processes are scheduled with 10 seconds of leaping at an infinite loop with, but each one of them interacts with another API, and I have no problem with that but the issue when there's a data has been inserted to the table to handled and Both of spring processes were working at the same time Separation occurs, one of both process one of those processes will be automatically stopped, from my side I have created Unix cob that checks the status for each of these processes and runs the disconnected process but my inquiry about why something like this happened and is there any idea to avoid this within java?

English is not my tongue language, feel free to update my question

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "Separation occurs in one of both process"?

Comment: @JensSchauder sorry for my language, i meant one of those processes will  be automatically stopped , both of these processes are running with an infinite loop and the issue when both are working at the same time